# Docker-compose "ports": listen on multiple IP addresses / IP range

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Instead of listening to a single IP address like e.g. localhost:

```
ports:
- "127.0.0.1:80:80"
```

I want the container to only listen to a local network, i.e. e.g.:

```
ports:
- "10.0.0.0/16:80:80"

ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.SERVICE.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

Is this possible?

*I don't want to use things like swarm mode etc., yet.*

---

If IP range is not supported, maybe at least multiple IP addresses like `10.0.0.2` and `10.0.0.3`?

```
ERROR: for CONTAINER  Cannot start service SERVICE: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint CONTAINER (...): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 10.0.0.3:80: bind: cannot assign requested address

ERROR: for SERVICE  Cannot start service SERVICE: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint CONTAINER (...): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 10.0.0.3:80: bind: cannot assign requested address
```

Or is it not even supported to listen to `10.0.0.3` ?

The host machine is connected to `10.0.0.0/16`:

```
> ifconfig
ens10: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 10.0.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 10.0.0.2
        inet6 f**0::8**0:ff:f**9:b**7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether **:00:00:**:**:**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Comment: Is the `10.0.0.0/16` your physical local network or virtual internal network connecting containers?

Comment: It's some sort of a physical network, it connects multiple virtual machines - the network is from my VM provider, hope this answers your question?

Comment: I see. You want to be able access container running at VM1 from VM2, right?

Comment: Yes, the machine where the container is running is VM1, and I want VM2 and VM3 to be able to access VM1 via this "private network".

Comment: is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64867860/13946204) answer you question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Listening to a single IP address` seems not correct. The service is listening **at** an IP address.

Let's say your VM has two network interfaces (ethernet cards):

Network 1 → subnet: `10.0.0.0/24` and IP `10.0.0.100`
Network 2 → subnet: `10.0.1.0/24` and IP `10.0.1.200`

- If you set `127.0.0.1:80:80` that means that your service listening at `127.0.0.1`'s ([localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost)) port 80.
- If you want to access service from `10.0.0.0/24` subnet you should set `10.0.0.100:80:80` and use `http://10.0.0.100:80` address to be able connect your container from external hosts

If you want to access service from multiple networks simultaneously you can bind the container port to multiple ports, where the IP is the [connection source IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_network)):

```
ports:
  - 10.0.0.100:80:80
  - 10.0.1.200:80:80
  - 127.0.0.1:80:80
```

<sub>And don't forget to open 80 port at VM's firewall, if a firewall exists and restricts that network</sub>

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Thanks a lot for clarification: I don't have to define the IPs who can access, but the "own" IP address of the host where the container to be accessed is running. By choosing its IP address in the `10.0.0.X` network, I allow others from that network to access the container. I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as I got it to work.

Comment: I marked this as the accepted answer as it answered my original question: how can a container be accessible by multiple other IP addresses within the network `10.0.0.1`. And this answer was earlier than @David Maze reply which also answered this question.

Comment: @hb0 If you want to listen on all IPs, I recommend to use `0.0.0.0:80:80` or just `80:80` without IP address (same as `0.0.0.0`) instead of `10.0.0.100:80:80 + 10.0.1.200:80:80 + ...`. Why? because when IP change to `10.0.0.101` container start fail. That may be critical for auto-scalable environments with dynamic IP addresses

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Currently, we intent to use a Docker container orchestration tool as soon as we start (auto-)scaling, i.e. then we can switch back to docker linking for this case. The approach discussed here is just for simple setups with 1 node per service.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood this field.

When you map 127.0.0.1:80:80 you will map interface 127.0.0.1 from your host to your container.

In the case of the  127.0.0.1 you can only access it from inside your host.

When you map 10.0.0.3:80:80 you will map interface 10.0.0.3 from your host to your container. And all ip who can access 10.0.0.3 will have acces to your docker container mapping.

But in anycase this field will not do any filtering about who access this container

EDIT: After your modification i've seen my misunderstood about your question.

You want docker to create "bridge interface" to not share the ip of your host.

I don't think this is possible when using the port mapping

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read it multiple times, but found it really hard to really understand it (but more because if the language, I'm afraid). As soon as I figured everything out I'll suggest an edit to your answer, to clarify your message, at least from my standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you give Compose `ports:` (or `docker run -p`) an IP address, it must be a specific known IP address of a host interface, or `0.0.0.0` for "all interfaces".  The Docker daemon gives this specific IP address to a [**bind**(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) call, which takes an address and not a network, and follows the rules in [**ip**(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/ip) for IPv4.

With the output you show, you can only bind containers to `10.0.0.2`.  If you want to use other IP addresses on the same network, you also need to assign them to the host; see for example [How can I (from CLI) assign multiple IP addresses to one interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547289/how-can-i-from-cli-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-interface) on Ask Ubuntu, and then you can bind a container to the newly-added address.

If your system is on multiple physical networks, you can have any number of `ports:` so long as the host address and host port are unique.  In particular you can have multiple `ports:` that all forward to the same container port.

```yaml
ports:
  # make this visible to the external load balancer on port 80
  - '192.168.17.2:80:3000'
  # also make this visible to the internal network also on port 80
  - '10.0.0.2:80:3000'
  # and the management network but on port 3000
  - '10.99.0.36:3000:3000'
```

Again, the host must already have these IP addresses in the `ifconfig` output.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to bind the container to multiple networks. From @rzlvmp 's answer I noticed my mistake, that I have to use the container's IP not the IPs which "may access" the container. I'll have a look which answer I eventually mark as accepted. Cheers!